# Test If The Array Index Equals The Array Value

Tags: javascript, arrays, undefined, reduce

The code is to return the lowest index in an array when the value in the array is the same as the index. If there are no matches i should return -1. For example:

```
indexEqualsValue([-8,0,2,5])
output: 2 //array[2] == 2

indexEqualsValue([-1,0,3,6])
output: -1  //no matches
```

The code works when there are no matches or if the length of the array is zero, but not at other times. I think the problem is the first condition in my if statement. I don't necessarily want an answer, more tips on what I should check/rewrite.

Thanks!

```
function indexEqualsValue(a) {
    return a.reduce((acc, currV, currI) => {
      if (currI === currV) {
        return currV;
      }
      return -1;
  }, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You could just find the index with [`Array#findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex).

```js
const indexEqualsValue = array => array.findIndex((v, i) => v === i);

console.log(indexEqualsValue([-8, 0, 2, 5])); //  2
console.log(indexEqualsValue([-1, 0, 3, 6])); // -1
```

Answer (score 1):

[`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) exits when it matches, so you can use it to quickly find what you need:

```js
const indexEqualsValue = array => {
  let match;
  
  const didMatch = array.some((v, i) => {
    match = i;
    return v === i;
  })
  
  return didMatch ? match : -1;
}

console.log(indexEqualsValue([-8,0,2,5]))
console.log(indexEqualsValue([-8,0,2,5,0]))
console.log(indexEqualsValue([-1,0,3,6]))
```

---

nina-scholz's answer is better, the only advantage of using `some` over `findIndex` is that `some` is supported in ie whereas it seems `findIndex` is not.

Comment: I'm fairly sure it won't; `some` exits when it matches. I've added an example now to prove that.

Comment: Oh my bad. You are correct. I was fiddling with helping OP with fixing reduce and it won't break

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i = 0,c=0;i < arr.length; i++ ) { 
    if(arr[i] == i) {
        c = 1;
        break; 
    }
}   
if( c == 0 ) {  
    print(c);  
} else {  
    print (i);  
}
```